# Advanced Installer prerequisites - Pre-install in silent mode

Tags: c#, windows, advanced-installer

We are going to release an application developed using C# and now recently we faced a problem building set up application using Advanced Installer 15.6.
To put it in more detail we are going to one to install .NET Framework 4.6.1 in silent mode (with no window).
We tried to find the solution for several hours and also asked Advanced Installer team, but haven't find or receive any answer.
Tried as followings.

```
/q
/quiet
...
```

Hope to receive quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you launch the setup package elevated, for instance by using **Run as admin** , or as a child process within an elevated process? If the setup package is not launched elevated the prerequisite installer will fail to install silently from what I know.

Comment: I have lunched setup file as administrator. but not working in silent mode.